# Do Until across three non-contiguous columns

Tags: excel, vba

This code checks if the cell is a number or not to delete it.

There are three columns that I have to do this. I want to process columns b, e and h.

Do Until only goes through it once and stops, leaving the loop. It changes the col to 5 or 8 as it is in the for.

Another problem is that if the cell is empty, VBA fills in 0 as a value. Is there a way to leave the cell blank instead of putting 0?

```vb
Sub copy()

    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Col As Long
      
    Row = 1

    For Col = 2 To 8 Step 3
    
        Do Until Cells(Row, 1).Value = ""
    
            If IsNumeric(Cells(Row, Col)) = False Then
                Cells(Row, Col).Clear            
            Else
     
                Cells(Row, Col).Select
    
                If Cells(Row, Col).Value = 0 Then
                    Cells(Row, Col).Value = (Cells(Row, Col).Value) * 1
                    Cells(Row, Col).NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
                Else
                    Cells(Row, Col).Value = CDec((Cells(Row, Col).Value))
                    Cells(Row, Col).NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
                End If
                
            End If
            Row = Row + 1
        Loop
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Without some indentation to the code, it is difficult to understand what problem you have. Now, it is a little clearer... Then, which columns do you want processing? "B, E and H"? Why do you use the code line `Cells(Row, Col).Select`?

Comment: Because you don't reset `Row` between the columns?

Comment: This I want to process columns b, e and h. How could I reset it.. I thought of putting the code 3 times.. Thank you

Comment: Are the items to find based on a formula?

Comment: No.. based in text or number thank

Comment: By putting the `Row = 1` inside the loop rather than outside?

Comment: I didn't try to do that

Comment: but what's going wrong is that it goes through all the rows of column b.. it doesn't go to the column "e" it stops.. it doesn't go further

Comment: It does to go to column e, and immediately stops processing it because `Cells(Row, 1).Value` is `""` in the column e, because you do not reset the `Row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the columns, but use special cells to determine if it is text or a number.

Based on your comment, it is either text or numbers, not sure why you would need to times by 1, or make value=value.

```
Sub UsingSpecialCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, LstRw As Long
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        For Col = 2 To 8 Step 3
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, Col), .Cells(LstRw, Col))
            
            On Error Resume Next
            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2).ClearContents
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            On Error Resume Next

            rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 21).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
            On Error GoTo 0

        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clean Data: Apply Consistent Formatting in Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateCurrency()

    ' Define constants.
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2 ' adjust: you have headers, right?
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    ' Hard to believe that you know the column numbers but not the worksheet name.
    
    ' Calculate the last row, the row of the bottom-most non-empty cell
    ' in the worksheet.
    Dim lCell As Range
    Set lCell = ws.UsedRange.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = lCell.Row

    Dim crg As Range, cell As Range, cValue, Col As Long
      
    For Col = 2 To 8 Step 3 ' to not introduce further complications
        
        ' Reference the single-column range from the first to the last row.
        Set crg = ws.Range(ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, Col), ws.Cells(LastRow, Col))
        
        ' Clear the undesired values (all except empty and numeric values).
        For Each cell In crg.Cells
            ' Write the cell value to a variant variable.
            cValue = cell.Value
            ' Check if the value is not numeric.
            If Not IsNumeric(cValue) Then cell.ClearContents
        Next cell
        
        ' Apply the formatting to the whole column range so it takes effect
        ' if you decide to add numbers to the empty cells.
        crg.NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00" ' "\$ #,##0.00" if $ is not native
        ' Copy the values to memory, and copy them back to the range
        ' for the formatting to affect the remaining numerics
        ' (numbers and numbers formatted as text).
        crg.Value = crg.Value
    
    Next Col

    MsgBox "Currency updated.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Comment: I just had a problem with the macro.. when I run it some numbers appear store as text.. how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Once iteration through the column 2 last row value is complete, blank row gets iterated and as per the condition *Cells(Row, 1).Value = ""* gets true and terminates the do until loop.

I have made small changes to your code and created the perfect working solution.

```
Sub copy()
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim Col As Long
  
    Row = 1

    Dim row_i As Integer
    row_i = Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown).Row

    For Col = 2 To 8 Step 3
        Row = 1
      Do Until Row > row_i

        If IsNumeric(Cells(Row, Col).Value) = False Then
            Cells(Row, Col).Clear
        Else
 
            Cells(Row, Col).Select

            If Cells(Row, Col).Value = 0 Then

               Cells(Row, Col).Value = (Cells(Row, Col).Value) * 1
               Cells(Row, Col).NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"

            Else

                Cells(Row, Col).Value = CDec((Cells(Row, Col).Value))
                Cells(Row, Col).NumberFormat = "$ #,##0.00"
            End If

  
        End If
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

  Next
End Sub
```